# Что в нем не правильно? В JS

Tags: javascript

```
var a=[5,12,3,11];
var b=[];
a[99]=7;

function c(){
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    b[i]=(Math.pow(a[i],2));
};
              return b;

}

console.log(c());
```

хочу чтоб написал 25,144,9,121 и 49.....но у меня много NaN-ов

Comment: var a=[5,12,3,11];
var b=[];
a[99]=7;

function c(){
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    b[i]=(Math.pow(a[i],2));
};
              return b;
   
}

console.log(c());

Comment: это тебя надо спросить "что неправильно"?

Comment: хочу чтоб написал 25,144,9,121 и 49.....но у меня много NaN-ов

Comment: те номера, которые в исходном массиве - возводятся в степень же.. там всё норм

Comment: (100) [25, 144, 9, 121, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 49]

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле всё работает. Просто когда ты пишешь так:

```
var a=[5,12,3,11];
a[99]=7;
```

то в итоге массив с 0-вого элемента по 3 заполняется числами, а также 99 (на самом деле 98) - имеет значение 7. Однако массиву надо заполнить пространство между 3 и 98 элементами и он заполняет их `undefined`. В итоге в массиве `a` с 4 по 97 элемент имеют значения `undefined` и в целом выглядит так:

```
 (100) [5, 12, 3, 11, undefined × 95, 7]
```

А дальше в цикле `Math.pow(undefined,2)` конечно же превращается в `NaN`

Comment: спасибо,,а может делать так чтобы не преврашалься в NaN с помощью if?

Comment: Если я напишу так:
for(var i in a){
    console.log(Math.pow(a[i],2));
}

все правильно..но можем мы сделать так же без for(var i in a)??

Comment: @Programmer если ты пытаешься сделать ассоциативный массив, как в PHP, то проще сделать `а` и `b` объектом, вместо массива

Comment: Ок..спасибо Алексей